# Best version control tool

Tags: version-control, flex4

I am working on an Adobe Flex project. We are a team of 6 people working from the same location. In this situation which version control tool will be the best?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "BEST" tool in the market. It all depends on your needs. There are a lot of available options like git, svn, mercurial etc. If your team members are already comfortable with version control, believe me, what ever you use, won't make much of a difference. Most of the projects (private as well as open source) I am working on are using git. I personally think that git is some what overly complicated because of a lot of features that are rarely used. People might think otherwise, but its just my personnel opinion.

If you and your team are going to use some thing like this for the first time, I would say go for `svn`.
It is very easy to setup and configure and there are a lot of GUI clients (like tortoise svn) which will make your life easier.
Else go for `GIT`.

As smart people say, its better to concentrate on the actual product that you are building than to think about and pick one of the million tools available in the market. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is highly contentious, but current favourites are git and Mercurial.

Git is very quick but has crap Windows support.  Mercurial is slower but is supported well on all popular platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It basically depends on your workflow. Each tool has it's advantages over some of the others.

I prefer git.

Some more info:

- http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/
- [Popularity of Git/Mercurial/Bazaar vs. which to recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995636/popularity-of-git-mercurial-bazaar-vs-which-to-recommend)